Smooth merging in curve to mesh
I generate a bunch of curves in geometry nodes that are then supposed to be converted to mesh with curve circle as the fill curve. I want the mesh to be merged smoothly at points of contact. something like the result of the skin modifier. voxel remesh generates too many verticies and results in some quality issues. Converting to volume and then back to mesh has the same problem while being very slow on top.

Can you please show the desired result with images? It is not clear from the text alone what exactly the goal of this question is. In the best case, you also share your Blend file with us to avoid misunderstandings: https://blend-exchange.com/

I don't think anyone has reproduced the skin modifier in geonodes.
